# Is it possible to embed a comment box within the video player that can be accessed by a click?

Tags: javascript, jquery, flash

So I was wondering if there was a way to create a video player or edit some open source video player with the functionality that users can add comments straight from the video player. So if you're trying to picture it, it would be something like this: the tool bar at the bottom would have the usual seek bar, volume control, play/pause buttons etc, and now an additional button that when clicked would trasform the tool bar into a text box which can be used to enter comments while watching videos. The comments would then be entered below the video.

Any help on trying to make something like this either using javascript or flash would be appreciated.

thakns

Answer (score 1):

Strictly related to the Flash side of your question, to make a comment tool bar, would be fairly simple. To define the tool bar components and functionality, you can use states. One state can be 'normal' (play/stop, seek, full screen etc.) and another would be 'comment' (a text area and a submit button). This would cover the client side. I suggest this approach, because you can use transitions when switching states. An alternative solution would be to use a view stack.

In order to update the comments list (below the player), you could do something like this: Every time a comment is submitted (assuming there is no moderation involved), a request is sent to the server (from Flash) with the comment data (name, content etc.), and in turn, if all went OK, the server sends a response to Flash. When this cycle is complete, you can issue from Flash an 'external' call, which basically means call some JavaScript function.

And finally, that function sends an asynchronous request to update the comments lists.

Hope this helps. Have a great day!